# Deploying a precompiled update for .NET web application?

Tags: .net, deployment

We have a number of web applications in .NET 4.0 (written using Visual Studio 2010) which are precompiled and deployed onto the production servers.

Currently when we do an update we replace all the existing files with the updated binaries. This updates the application but it also restarts the application so all users have to log back in again.

The deployed binaries basically consist of a single .dll for every project in my solution.

Is there any way the web application can be updated without interrupting any existing users?

I realise one way to do this would be to deploy the source file and have them be compiled by the webserver on the fly but this is not really a viable option for us.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is supported in the CLR with the AppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyFiles property.  When turned on, the CLR makes a copy of an assembly before loading it.  So only the copy is locked and the original can be overwritten.  This feature is explicitly designed for ASP.NET, a CLR host that recycles AppDomains easily.  There is an excellent [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx) about it that shows how you configure it.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. So this isn't something that can simply be 'enabled' in the web.config, it has to be actually compiled within the application itself?

Comment: I believe ShadowCopyFiles is enabled by default. Therefore my problem now seems to be that the Session is lost when I update files. This causes my users to be logged out. Is this expected behaviour or not?

Comment: @cusimar9 - if your goal is to preserve session while app is updated, have you tried StateServer session mode instead of in-proc? It's very easy to enable and use and no additional software is required (as opposite to SqlServer mode)

Comment: This was exactly my issue, thanks for the comment and I hope it helps someone else